# puts() command and pointer: don't print

Tags: c

I have the following listing:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 char strA [80] = "A string to be used for demonstration purposes";
 char strB [80];
 int main (void) {
     char * pA;
     char * pB;
     puts (strA);
     pA = strA;
     puts (pA);
     pB = strB;

     putchar ('\n');
     while (* pA! = '\0')
     {
         * pB ++ = * pA ++;
         puts (pB); <<<< line c
     }
     * pB = '\0';
     puts (strB);
     return 0;
 }
```

because by inserting the line c, which should, according to my intentions, print the contents of `strA` increasing it and going to the head each time as many times as it is along the array `strA` it prints only empty lines, while if instead of line c I insert `puts (pA);`

Does the listing work by printing out the contents of `strA`, decreasing it and going to the top each time as many times as long as the `strA` array is?

Comment: You are printing the contents of `strB` not `strA`. You need to null terminate the string _before_ printing it or it _isn't a string_ and can't be used as one.

Comment: What output do you expect for this program?

Comment: @Lundin `strB` is initialized to 0.

Comment: As Lundin already mentioned, you don't print `strA` but `strB`. Furthermore you print `pB` after you incremented it. That means `pB` points to the location behind the last character you copied from `pA`. As `strB` is initialized to 0 on startup, you only print empty strings.

Comment: @Gerhardh Ah right, I didn't see that these were file scope variables because of the floppy formatting. But relying on static storage zero-initialization to implicitly null-terminate things for you is very bad practice.

Comment: Yes I know it has to print the contents of strB.
strB before the "while" loop is empty, while during the "while" loop, it assumes a value equal to a letter in strA, gradually increasing for each loop until it is srtA == strB.
so in the first cycle I would expect it to print a single 'A' first.
On the second cycle the 'A' plus a space.
On the third cycle the 'A'spazio's'.
On the 4th cycle 'a st'.
and so on.

Comment: As I wrote, you increment your pointer after copying the character. If you want to print the character you just copied, you need to remove the `++` from `*pB++ = ` and increment `pB` after printing.

Comment: so this doesn't happen because puts () prints a memory location that is momentarily still empty. If you were to put puts (pB) before '* pB ++ = * pA ++;' of the 'while' loop should print the memory content previously assigned by the loop. correct? but this does not happen. why?

Comment: No, that is not what I wrote. You must do `*pB = *pA++; puts(pB); pB++;` If you only move `puts` before the assignment, the problem stays exactly the same.

Comment: OK! I got it. thank you very much for your great patience